# Can't install Ubuntu live dvd

Tags: boot, system-installation

Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04. I get this error on start up after Ubuntu logo start up screen:

```
(0.244097) PMP 00:04: can't evaluate -CRS 12298
(4.275880) ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED
```

Can anyone give me an idea on how to fix this?

Using iso burnt to dvd on hp amd athon 11 x 2 processor 4 gb ram nividia GeForce 61505e.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details, we have no idea what you're talking about. How are you installing? CD? USB? Which Ubuntu? On what hardware? When is this error shown?

Comment: installing using downloaded iso burnt to dvd

Comment: Please _[edit]_ your question as I asked (comments are hard to read and easy to miss) and add the information I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supplement the main boot options, the `F1-F6` keys provide additional information and boot options for special circumstances.

These options are accessed by pressing `any` key before the Welcome screen appears.

`F6` -- Other Options. `ACPI` and `EDD` options which may help if your computer does not support or has problems with these systems. 
Highlight the selection and press the `Enter` key or `Space` key to select it.

In addition to displaying a popup menu, the `F6` key also activates in-line editing of the boot command.

Pressing `F6` brings up the popup menu. Pressing `Esc`, whether selections were made or not, removes the popup window but opens the boot command for editing.

The phrase `Boot Options` is fixed on the left side of the screen. The command scrolls off to the left to leave the right end available for appending.

The user may add additional inputs before or after the `--` . Allow one space between each additional input.

Try add the `acpi=off pci=noacpi` options.